# Loop through multi selection value of Jekins Parameter BooleanParam

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have on-premise Jenkins node slave that are running. The value of each param is the nodename. For example the nodename I have is (value1,value2,value3)
Suppose a user select a value1 and value2 in the parameter options in the checkbox, I want to be able to loop the selected params and pass the value to the node($selected).

That means Jenkins will connect to value1 and value2 node. Any Idea how to do this?

The code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy


properties([
    parameters([

booleanParam(name: 'value1', defaultValue: false, description: '') ,
booleanParam(name: 'value2', defaultValue: false, description: '') ,
booleanParam(name: 'value3', defaultValue: false, description: '') 
    ])
])


stage('stash'){

 Loop here // 
 
    node('$selected'){

 


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do something like the below?

```
node {
    properties([
    parameters([

booleanParam(name: 'value1', defaultValue: false, description: '') ,
booleanParam(name: 'value2', defaultValue: false, description: '') ,
booleanParam(name: 'value3', defaultValue: false, description: '') 
    ])
])

    stage('Stash') { 
       def list = []
       if("$value1" == "true") {
           list.add("value1")
       }
       if("$value2" == "true") {
           list.add("value2")
       }
       if("$value3" == "true") {
           list.add("value3")
       }
       
       list.each { node ->
            echo "$node"
            node('$node'){}
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ycr. I am having issue with parameters with space and hypen. It works with the values without space. For example "Staging Database"  has space and could not recognise the variable and also variables with hypen on the if ("Staging Database") The error is hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Staging Database for class: WorkflowScript

Comment: resolved now. thanks. use this if("${params['Staging Database']}" == "true") {